# Run different servers as one server

Tags: server

For some websites, for example, Github, they have a lot of servers. But how can they run these different servers under one domain?

For example, I have two servers host my blog and my project. Server one's host name is `1.test.com` and server two's host name is `2.test.com`. Is there any way that I can run these two servers as one so that I can visit my blog as `test.com/blog` and my project as `test.com/project`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Nginx to be proxy server:

nginx.conf

```
location ~/blog {
   proxy_pass 1.test.com
}

location ~/project {
   proxy_pass 2.test.com
}
```

Comment: awesome! what about apache?

Comment: Sorry, I havn't used Apache:(